# An error occurred while sending the request

Tags: c#, xml

Eu estou gerando um xml de lote de rps, e ao envelopar, e adicionar `![CDATA[` ele pula linha, pensei que fosse algo com os cadastros, porém eu gerei lote de apenas um rps, um por um, pra ver se daria esse mesmo problema, porém não deu, e quando eu adiciono todos, ele pula linha, fica dessa forma:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Alguém pode me ajudar, de o pq isso acontecer?

Eu creio que pode ser algum caractere que está fazendo pular a linha, mas até então não sei qual pode ser. Isso ocorreu na segunda geração.

Eu utilizo este código:

```
 string soapEnvelope = string.Empty;

        var item = db.Empresas.SingleOrDefault(t => t.Id == idempresa);
        soapEnvelope += "<S:Envelope xmlns:S=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\" xmlns:tns=\"http://www.betha.com.br/e-nota-contribuinte-ws\">";
        soapEnvelope += "<S:Body><tns:" + ws + "><nfseCabecMsg><![CDATA[";
        soapEnvelope += CabecMsg;
        soapEnvelope += "]]></nfseCabecMsg><nfseDadosMsg><![CDATA[";
        soapEnvelope += document.LastChild.OuterXml.Replace("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>", string.Empty);
        soapEnvelope += "]]></nfseDadosMsg></tns:" + ws + "></S:Body></S:Envelope>";
        MemoryStream stream = stringToStream(soapEnvelope.Replace("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>", string.Empty));
        webRequest.ContentLength = stream.Length;
        Stream requestStream = webRequest.GetRequestStream();
        stream.WriteTo(requestStream);

        document.LoadXml(soapEnvelope);

        document.PreserveWhitespace = false;
        document.Save(caminho);
        System.Xml.Linq.XDocument doc = System.Xml.Linq.XDocument.Load(caminho);
        doc.Save(caminho, System.Xml.Linq.SaveOptions.DisableFormatting);

        this.XmlDocNFSe = document;
```

Não deveria estar quebrando linha.

Comment: Imagino que esta quebra de linha seja apenas por conta da visualização no browser. Tenta abrir o xml com um editor de texto simples e verifique se está gerando espaço ou quebra de linha.

Comment: @WagnerSoares no editor de texto também está pulando linha.